# POST endpoint created with Node.js not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a database in Mlab that is MongoDB that has two collections and I am trying to make a POST endpoint to which I can post whatever a user has entered in a commentbox. However I am doing something wrong, because when I test my endpoint with Postman it says 404 that the endpoint is not found. Trying to post via the commentbox does not work too ofcourse. This is the url to my post endpoint:
`https://astroecstatic-express.herokuapp.com/comments`. However if I run this in the browser it displays an empty array, so how come I get a 404 error when trying to POST? What am I doing wrong and how can I make my POST endpoint? Here is my node.js server:

```
// Requiring the dependencies
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const itemRoutes = express.Router();
let Comment = require('./comment.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://admin:SomeUSersecretpassword.mlab.com:41968/heroku_hc9xjmcl", { useNewUrlParser: true } )

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function() {
  console.log('Connection to MongoDB established succesfully!');
});

// Serve static assets
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('build'));
}

itemRoutes.route('/').get( async (req, res) => {
  let collection = connection.collection("posts");
  let response = await collection.find({})
  .toArray();
  res.send(response);
});

itemRoutes.route('/comments').get( async (req, res) => {
  let collection = connection.collection("comments");
  let response = await collection.find({})
  .toArray();
  res.send(response);
});

itemRoutes.route('/comments')
.post((req, res) => {
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   let comment = new Comment(req.body);
   comment.save()
   .then(comment => {
     res.status(200).json({comment})
   })
   .catch(err => {
     res.status(400).send('failed')
   })
});


app.use('/', itemRoutes);
app.use('/comments', itemRoutes);


app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Server is running on' + ' ' + PORT);
})
```

and my post component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class CommentBox extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.path = window.location.href;
        this.postId = this.path.split("/").slice(-1)[0];
      }

      state = {
        userComments: []
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const fetchPosts = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get('https://astroecstatic-express.herokuapp.com/comments');
            this.setState({...this.state, userComments: res.data})
          };
          fetchPosts();
        }

          getCommentData = (res) => {
           let today = new Date();
           let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
           let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
           let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

            today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
            const commentContent = document.querySelector(".comment-box-container__div-comment-box").textContent;
            axios.post('https://astroecstatic-express.herokuapp.com/comments', {title: commentContent, date: today, commentId: this.postId })
            window.location.reload();
           }


       render() {
        let currentPostComments = this.state.userComments.filter((item) => {
       return item.commentId === this.postId
       })

        return(
            <div className="comment-box-container">
             <div className="comment-box-container__div">
             <button className="comment-box-container__post-comment-btn" onClick={this.getCommentData}> Post Comment</button>
             <div className="comment-box-container__div-comment-box" contentEditable="true"></div>
             </div>

             <div className="comment-box-container__show-coments-section">
             {currentPostComments.map(comment => 
             <section>
             <h3>{comment.date}</h3>
            {comment.title}
            </section>
            )}
             </div>
             </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CommentBox;
```

Comment: You said the route you are posting to was `/comments`, but your code only shows a post route for `/userComments`.  Plus configuring the `itemRoutes` router twice for two different base routes is likely wrong too.

Comment: @jfriend00 the ```userCommetns``` was a typo, I updated my question. In my original code the endpoint is /comments but it still doesn't work. I need to both GET and POST from that endpoint, that's why they are configured twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to create both a `.get()` and a `.post()` route for `/comments` on a router:

```
 itemRoutes.get("/comments", function(req, res, next) {
      // code here
 });

 itemRoutes.post("/comments", function(req, res, next) {
      // code here
 });

 app.use(itemRoutes);
```

You can also use `.route()` instead like this:

```
 itemRoutes.route("/comments").get(function(req, res, next) {
      // code here
 }).post(function(req, res, next) {
      // code here
 });

 app.use(itemRoutes);
```

And, you don't even really have a compelling case for using a router for these two routes.  You could also just do:

```
 app.get("/comments", ...);
 app.post("/comments", ...);
```

Or

```
 app.route("/comments")
    .get(...)
    .post(...);
```

And, not even use a router for just two top level routes.

Comment: No.  Your `app.use()` doesn't look this way and you're not using `.route()` like I show.

Comment: Isn't that what I have been doing?: 
```
itemRoutes.route('/comments').get( async (req, res) => {
  let collection = connection.collection("comments");
  let response = await collection.find({})
  .toArray();
  res.send(response);
});

itemRoutes.route('/comments')
.post((req, res) => {
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   let comment = new Comment(req.body);
   comment.save()
   .then(comment => {
     res.status(200).json({comment})
   })
   .catch(err => {
     res.status(400).send('failed')
   })
});
```

Comment: FYI, the only point of use `.route()` is to chain multiple routes together on the same path.  If you're not going to chain multiple routes on one `itemRoutes.route()` statement, then there's no point in using `.route()` at all and you may as well use the first method I show above.

Comment: @MahmaDeva - Also, note that this case doesn't really for a router at all as these are all top level routes defined where `app` is known.  You could just do `app.get()` and `app.post()` too with no router at all.